# Como modifico un script para que funcione cuando lo cargo adentro de un div?

Tags: jquery

Quiero agregar una galería de imágenes a mi sitio web, y como todas las secciones las cargo dentro de un div, cada vez que encuentro algún ejemplo  de galería que me gusta, deja de funcionar cuando lo cargo dentro de mi div "#section".
Por ejemplo, yo tengo mi index.html que es la que contiene el div "#section" y la galería que se llama imagenes.html. Cuando yo abro imagenes.html, funciona perfecto, pero cuando abro la index.html y cargo imagenes.html dentro de #section, deja de funcionar...
Intuyo que el problema puede andar por alguna variable que dice $(this), pero probe cambiándola de 2039432 formas y no logro pegarla para que funcione. Alguien podría ayudarme con esto?!

El código de imagenes.html se ve así:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Galeria</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="photostack.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="photostack.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(function(){
    $(".photostack").Photostack();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <ul class="photostack">
    <li><img src="fotos/foto1.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="fotos/foto2.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="fotos/foto3.jpg"></li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

y el de photostack.js se ve asi:

```
(function($){
  var getRand = function (a, b) {
        return ~~(Math.random() * (b - a + 1)) + a;
    }
    var getPrefix = function(){
      var userAgent = window.navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
      if(userAgent.indexOf("msie") != -1){
        return "-ms-";
      }else if(userAgent.indexOf("chrome") != -1 || userAgent.indexOf("safari") != -1){
        return "-webkit-"
      }else if(userAgent.indexOf("firefox") != -1){
        return "-moz-";
      }else if(userAgent.indexOf("opera") != -1){
        return "-o-";
      }else{
        return "";
      }
    }
    var def = {
      top:40,
      left:500,
      degFrom:-20,
      degTo:20,
      animation:"move",
      animationSpeed:500,
      timespan:0,
      auto:false,
      preventClick:false
    }
  $.prototype.Photostack = function(opt){
    opt = $.extend(def,opt);
    var $this = $(this);                //aca pienso yo que puede estar el problema
    var $children = $this.children();
    var prefix = getPrefix();
    var zindex = 0;
    var width = 0;
    var height = 0;
    $this.addClass("js-photostack");
    $children.each(function(){
      var $child = $(this);
      var rand = getRand(opt.degFrom,opt.degTo);
      var rotate = "rotate("+rand+"deg)";
      $child.css(prefix+"transform",rotate);
      $child.css("transform",rotate);
      $child.css("z-index",zindex);
      zindex++;
      if($child.width() > width){
        width = $child.width();
      }
      if($child.height() > height){
        height = $child.height();
      }
    });
    $this.width(width);
    $this.height(height);
    var finished = true;
    $this.click(function(e){
      if(e.originalEvent && opt.preventClick){
        return;
      }
      if(!finished){
        return;
      }
      finished = false;
      var max = 0;
      $children.each(function(){
        var current = parseInt($(this).css("z-index"));
        current++;
        $(this).css("z-index",current);
        if(current > max){
          max = current;
        }
      });
      var $child = $children.filter(function(){
        return max == $(this).css("z-index");
      });
      if(opt.animation == "move"){
        var animationStart = {top:opt.top,left:opt.left};
        var animationEnd = {top:0,left:0};
      }else if(opt.animation = "fade"){
        var animationStart = {opacity:0};
        var animationEnd = {opacity:1};
      }
      $child
      .animate(animationStart,opt.animationSpeed)
      .queue(function(next){
        $child.css("z-index",0);
        next();
      })
      .animate(animationEnd,opt.animationSpeed)
      .queue(function(next){
        finished = true;
        next();
      });
    });
    if(opt.auto){
      setInterval(function(){$this.click()},opt.timespan+opt.animationSpeed*2);
    }
  };
})(jQuery);
```

Desde ya muchas gracias, Leandro.

Comment: cómo estás cargando `imagenes.html` dentro del `div#section`? dependiendo de la forma el javascript del .html "cargado"  puede o no ejecutarse

Comment: Para cargar las diferentes paginas en el div #section estoy utilizando esto: $("#section").load("imagenes.html"); .

Comment: prueba moviendo el bloque script al final, justo antes del </body>. para saber si el `.load('imagenes.html')` está identificando bien el archivo como `dataType:html`(y ejecutando el javascript) ponele un `onload="console.log('estoy cargado')"` al tag`body` de `imagenes.html` el resto sería F12 y ver los eventos en la consola (si cargan los js, si identifica bien el elemento, etc)

Comment: Estaba al final originalmente, probando y probando lo movi al principio, pero volvi a dejarlo al final como me decis y fijandome en la consola encontre esto: "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).Photostack is not a function".

Comment: en la pestaña `network` indica si carga el `photostack.js`? si es así tal vez no esté parseando bien el tag, ponerlo mas explícito: `<script type="text/javascript" src="photostack.js"` aunque seguramente no le encuentra en la ruta (o aún no terminó de cargar el jQuery y no puede engancharse al chain de plugins)

Comment: El photostack.js lo carga, y aunque explicite mejor el script tampoco funciona, no puede ser que el script no encuentre los elementos porque ya no están en la pagina principal?! yo creo que dentro del photostack.js tendria q indicarle que todo eso es para lo que esta dentro del #section ahora... pero no se como hacerlo, y tampoco se si es acertada esta idea de que el script ya no encuentra la ruta por cargar la pagina dentro del div..

Comment: el código del photostack es estándar de plugin, tal vez se esté enganchando a otra instancia de jQuery? si cambias a `jQuery(".photostack").Photostack()` hay alguna pista?

Comment: Exactamente lo mismo, el ejemplo con el que estoy trabajando y la galeria que quiero agregar desde mi index dentro de #section es este: https://www.jqueryscript.net/download/Simple-Photo-Stack-Rotator-Plugin-with-jQuery-Photostack-js.zip , no te quiero hacer perder tiempo pero tal vez si en algún momento vos o alguien puede verlo, encuentran algo que a mi se me esta pasando contarles.

Comment: No deberías cargar un HTML con su `head` y `scripts` y todo eso dentro de un `div`. Si cargas un HTML completo deberías hacerlo con un `iframe` o si no solo cargar la lista de imágenes, los scripts y estilos ponerlos en `index.html`

Comment: Increíble, en un iframe no necesito hacer absolutamente ninguna modificación! funciona de una... pero no hay forma de hacerlo responsive no?!

Answer (score 0):

si probaste que funciona fuera de tu sitio y deja de funcionar cuando lo pones en ese div talves tienes un problema con el identificador, porque no pruebas cambiando el name y id por otro, se que no es muy sofisticado pero solo eso se me ocurre